# How to transfer my Eclipse Maven Selenium Webdriver TestNG Java project from one PC to another?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, webdriver, project

I am working at a place, but sometimes I bring some work home.
The problem is, however I try to export my project from my work computer and use it on my home computer, I get all kinds of errors, missing files and so on.

Is there a way to transfer the project flawlessly?
What kind of additional information should I provide?

I've tried exporting to a JAR. Importing fails
I've tried moving the whole project folder, and opening an existing Maven project - fails.

Comment: When you say export does it mean you are trying to export a project from a central repo like svn? If not this should be a simple straight forward process.

Comment: No, not from a central repo. I have my project in a folder on my desktop on my work PC, and I'd like for that to work just as well on my computer. But when I copy that folder and import it at home, I get some .classpath errors, and in SRC/TEST/ there are no classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the class path file. Zip the entire folder and take it. Ensure when importing into your other eclipse import it as a maven project and not as just a simple java project. Your class path file contains all the path of the src and jar folders. since the path will be different in your other system you will get such errors.